# How Can I Reduce Similarity Analysis of Multiple Time-Series Vectors into a Single Value?

Tags: time-series, python, similarities, signal-processing, cosine-similarity

I have ~15 independently-sourced vectors with about 1600 samples in each. They are basically continuous, ~1 Hz, from t=0 to 22 minutes. The nature of the dataset is such that the signals are definitely similar in some aspects, with peaks and troughs often occurring during the same periods, in response to stimuli.

How can I mathematically distill the similarity of all 15 vectors into one number? I'm relatively new to statistics, and I've seen the Pearson coefficient, cosine similarity, as well as some other methods but these seem mostly to be related to the comparison of exactly 2 vectors, and it seems it's not ideal to do all pairwise versions of these metrics. Can anyone point me in the right direction here, or give a summary of your recommended analysis? I'd prefer to implement in Python as the whole analysis pipeline thus far is built in it.

I'm attaching a raster plot of the data to help clarify, using matplotlib's pcolormesh so that the scale-minimum (0) is white, and the maximum (2) is scaled to black (rgb 255).

[image]

I trimmed the y-axis from the photo on purpose, in order to keep sensitive data anonymous, but it is the axis on which n=15

Update: on stack overflow, a user suggested that I "calculate a mean of all of those vectors and compute cosine similarity of all of them to it". This is obviously computationally reasonable and saves me from needing to perform 15! or n! pairwise calculations, but I can't quite wrap my head around whether it is statistically sound. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: nothing wrong with calculating the 15x15 correlation matrix and plotting it. (not 15 factorial)

Comment: whoops haha! I'll probably do that in addition to using the intraclass correlation coefficient to distill a time-series of single-value group similarity

Comment: NOPE. That doesn't make sense, does it? Can ICC be used when you only have one group?